# glTexImage2D won't work, but setting FragColor to vec4(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0) gives me red image

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm trying to write an image to the screen using a texture unit from OpenGL. As you  see, I wrote 0 to the tex Sampler2D because I'm using the 0th texture unit. I also did the vertices andd texture as rectangles. I checked for gl errors, there are none. I also changed FragColor to  `vec4(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0);`, and I indeed see a red image, which means my coordinates are rigth.

Here's my code:

```
    static unsigned char * d = new unsigned char[640*360*4];

    const GLfloat vertices_textures[20] = {
    //vertices            //positions
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};

    if (this->firstRun)
        {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 640*360*4; ++i)
            {
                d[i] = 255;
            }

            program = std::make_unique<Program>();
            Shader vertexShader(ShaderType::Vertex);
            vertexShader.load_from_string(vertexShaderSource);

            program->attach_shader(vertexShader);

            Shader fragmentShader(ShaderType::Fragment);
            fragmentShader.load_from_string(fragmentShaderSource);
            program->attach_shader(fragmentShader);

            program->link();

            vextexInLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program->get_id(), "aPos");

            textureInLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program->get_id(), "aTexCoord");

            glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayObject);

            glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices_textures), vertices_textures, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

            glVertexAttribPointer(vextexInLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void *)0);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(vextexInLocation);

            glVertexAttribPointer(textureInLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void *)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureInLocation);


            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            texLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program->get_id(), "tex");

            program->use();

            glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);

            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);

            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, 640, 360, 0,  GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, d);

            firstRun = false;
        }

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUniform1i(texLocation, 0);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
        glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Here are my shaders:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}
```

and

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(tex, TexCoord);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant "see" the image, because the texture is not mipmap complete.

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification; 8.17 Texture Completeness; page 306](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf#page=330&zoom=100,0,173)

> A texture is said to be *complete* if all the texture images and texture parameters required to utilize the texture for texture application are consistently defined.
>
> ... a texture is complete unless any of the following conditions hold true:
>
> - The minification filter requires a mipmap (is neither `NEAREST` nor `LINEAR`), and the texture is not mipmap complete.

The initial value of `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`. If you don't change it and you don't create mipmaps, then the texture is not "complete" and will not be "shown". See [`glTexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml).

Either set the minification filter to `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR`

```cpp
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

or generate mipmaps by [`glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml) to solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain properly. The image only appears red when I do `FragColor = vec4(1.0,0,0,1.0);`. If I do as in the code above, the image is black, I see nothing. I should see red with my code, or white with yours, but I don't see in any of them

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)` solves the issue

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. You can see the modification of the code I did

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Sorry, my fault, copy/paste issue. Of course `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` rather than `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER`